# DynamoDB Local process

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Good day programmers,

I'm having a problem with running my dynamoDB (Node js). 
I tried to change the version still i'm getting the error.

I hope that someone already encountered this error.

Any help will do.

Thanks.

[image]

Edit :
When adding running this command ($env:SLS_DEBUG="*") it shows a list of commands.
[image]

Comment: I don't have Powershell experience, but try setting the SLS_DEBUG environment variable first: `$env:SLS_DEBUG="*"` and then run the command again.

Comment: i tried so many ways and your approach is new. I will try this and will update you what happen, I'm just in the middle of something. Thanks

Comment: @MilanCermak I tried this I got the same error however there's an additional command.

I will add it on my question for you to see it.